# C++ Receiving input from the WASD keys?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a 3d game which uses user input, the WASD keys.

My code is as follows:

```
    PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    int key = (int)msg.wParam;

    if (msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN && !bKey && key == 'w')
    {
        g_yVelocity += g_yDelta;
    }
```

But when I hit the w key, it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: You cannot ignore the return value of PeekMessage().  WM_KEYDOWN reports *virtual* keys, that will never be a lower-case 'w'.  Use 'W' instead.  Easy to see btw, practice using the debugger.

Comment: Hans,  I tried using the 'W' instead, yet still doesn't work.

Comment: answer is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441457/keyboard-input-the-win32-message-loop

Answer (score 0):

This code should work.

This should be located in your message switch statement

```
#define VK_W 0x57 
//define macro for getAsyncKeyState

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_W))
    {
        g_yVelocity += g_yDelta;
    }
```

[code 1](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/6632/)

[code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649759/win-32-api-textinput)